# Eigen3 Sparse solver assertion fail

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix, eigen3

I have a problem when solving a large sparse system in Eigen 3.3.7 using the SparseLU solver. I get a runtime assertion error of:

> void Eigen::PlainObjectBase::resize(Eigen::Index) [with
> Derived = Eigen::Matrix<int, -1, 1>; Eigen::Index = long int]:
> Assertion ((SizeAtCompileTime == Dynamic &&
> (MaxSizeAtCompileTime==Dynamic || size<=MaxSizeAtCompileTime)) ||
> SizeAtCompileTime == size) && size>=0' failed.

After looking online I found that my problem is likely due to my matrix being very large and I need to change the Ordering type from `int` to `long int`, [see here](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=111967). Well changing `COLAMDOrdering` to either `COLAMDOrdering<Eigen::Index>` or `COLAMDOrdering<long int>` did not work. I get a compiler error:

> error: no match for call to
> ‘(Eigen::SparseQREigen::SparseMatrix<std::complex<double >,
> Eigen::COLAMDOrdering >::OrderingType {aka
> Eigen::COLAMDOrdering}) (const
> Eigen::SparseMatrixstd::complex<double >&,
> Eigen::SparseQREigen::SparseMatrix<std::complex<double >,
> Eigen::COLAMDOrdering >::PermutationType&)’   315 |
> ord(matCpy, m_perm_c);

It seems that `Eigen::Index` is just an alias for `long int` anyway. I tried using information from [this link](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=132256) but it didn't help.

For reference, the size of the system im trying to solve is N = 98,000

Comment: Can you share a snippet of code that reproduces this error?